# "Duplicate" label on question disappears

Tags: bug, status-norepro, caching

When leaving a question and going to another tab for a while, the question's `Duplicate` marking disappears. The question is also treated like it is brand new, with a banner to show new answers.

**Actual:**
[image: duplicate status]

**What happened after about 1 minute (without refreshing):**

[image: looks like brand new]

Comment: Maybe a moderator decided it was not a duplicate and removed it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28182475/revisions

Comment: @PythonMaster The question still exists and is still marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the sequence wrong. Based on the [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28182475/revisions), it started out with the title

> Is there a difference between "text" and 'text'?

which then changed to

> Is there a interpretation difference between "..." and '...'?

**after** it was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: All I did was load up the question with title "Is there a interpretation difference between "..." and '...'" and went to another tab to learn about keydown(). Then, I returned to the question. I took these screenshots back-to-back. I didn't notice that the title had changed to its original as well.

Comment: @DominatorX: You'll notice the same thing happen when you post a comment. Once you've posted it and (say) click to another post, then use the back button to return to the post that you commented on, the comment will seem to have "vanished". Refreshing brings it back...

Comment: I didn't use the back button at all. I opened a new tab, then switched back to my SO page.